# Programmatically adding an image to a UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationController that I instantiated programatically.
Is there a way to set the background to an image (how its done on many sites) instead of standard text.

I have found some code by overriding GRect but it ever gets called

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGRect currentRect = CGRectMake(0,15,200,25);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topHeader.png"]; [image     
drawInRect:currentRect]; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your -drawRect: definition like this in your root view controller's .m file:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGRect currentRect = CGRectMake(0,15,200,25);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topHeader.png"]; [image     
drawInRect:currentRect]; }

@end
```